# Magento 2 Can not save custom attribute for customer

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes

I am getting following error while register customer with API. It happen when i am try to save Company field.

```
"Property \"Company\" does not have accessor method \"getCompany\" in class
```

I have use `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` as a argument in my API interface.

let me know if anyone have idea.

Comment: show us the payload

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing error because [`getCompany`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressInterface.php#L136) method is property of [`Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressInterface.php#L15). So please access this property by loading customer address and then save the company field

Comment: But in my case company is custom attribute